# Check if a string starts with a possible range of values and extract the match

Tags: regex, bash

Given the following JavaScript code:

```
const branch = 'PRODUCT-1234-foobar';
const match = (/^(?:product|core|shop)-\d+/i).exec(branch);
const name = match ? match[0] : 'unknown';
```

Given a branch that starts with either `PRODUCT-`, `CORE-` or `SHOP-` and is followed by at least one number, this will give me the first part of the name of the branch, in this case `PRODUCT-1234`.

I've been trying to do the same in Bash, but I cannot seem to make it work. How would I do this? The answer should *preferably* be case-insensitive.

Comment: Your JS regex contains a typo: by swapping `:` and `?`, instead of using a non-capturing group you made it capturing and allowed an optional `:` to be matched.

Comment: Woops, thanks. Well, question probably still stands!

Comment: Yes, sure, it does not really make any difference, just bear in mind if you want to further use it and avoid matching [`:product-345`](https://regex101.com/r/oxQCjS/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `shopt -s nocasematch` to make the subsequent match case insensitive (see [this source](http://www.unix.com/302318460-post2.html?s=d3adcb7c722dbc4e2325398440e9885b)).

Use

```
shopt -s nocasematch
branch='PRODUCT-1234-foobar'
reg="^(product|core|shop)-[0-9]+"
if [[ $branch =~ $reg ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]};
fi
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/q4i97f).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - string start
- `(product|core|shop)`  - one of the alternatives
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits.

The `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` stands for the whole match value.

Comment: I can confirm this does precisely what I wanted, plus the bonus of case-insensitivity is also really nice! Thanks!

Comment: The other option for case insensitivity would be to use ${branch,,} in the above test, assuming bash version 4+.  You would then not need the shopt call

Comment: @grail It is interesting. However, that way, [`product-1234` will be returned](https://ideone.com/HIcggs), not `PRODUCT-1234` since each matched letter will be in lowercase. Not sure it is expected.